# How to combine RAND and DESC in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
$msg_check = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 5");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($msg_check)) {
$comment = $row['comment'];
$nickname = $row['nickname'];
```

What I need to do is take 5 comments with most replies and sort them randomly.
I've tried by combining RAND with DESC, but failed :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply an outer query that uses `RAND()` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM msgs 
  WHERE name='$name' 
  ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 5) AS t
ORDER BY RAND()
```

**Note:** It is always preferable to explicitly name each field in the `SELECT` clause instead of using `*`.

Comment: Or you can simply randomise the array

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM msgs where name='$name' ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 5) 
 ORDER BY rand()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think RAND() and DESC is not possible in single query in your case. 
You should fetch result and then try array_rand($your_array,5) function.